# Styling <area> HTML tag using CSS not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, area

I have this working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8439/).

By typing an "a" in the input-field, the selected area-tag gets another opacity:

```
$( "area[data-name^='" + input + "']" ).css( "opacity" , ".25" )
```

But the problem is, that there is no visual effect happening, even though jQuery code executes correctly?

Could anybody please help to get an visual effect on the area-tag??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you looking to turn one quarter of the image semi-transparent? That's not at all what maps are for, and they cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: just to make the area look different e.g. transparency, grayscale?? is there any way to add a class to each area and style via jquery?

Comment: No, no there isn't. That isn't what `<area>` is for. You cannot use it to apply styles, it is the wrong tool for this job. Consider using four `<a>` tags, each set to use that image as their background, but anchored so they stitch together. Then you can independently adjust their opacity.

Comment: i got an other way using the list-tag around the area: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8443/ but there is still no visual effect, anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

The `area` tag just defines space in which the user can click, there is no visual representation of it so you can't really use CSS directly to style it.

You would probably want to use JavaScript to overlay a transparent image over the top of your image map to accomplish what you're trying to do:

#### [jQuery plugin MapHilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/): [Example 1](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html#) [Example 2](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html) [Example 3](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html)

#### [Mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/)

Comment: i got a workaround maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8443/ , but there is still no visual effect ? could you refer to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: When i type an "a" in the input-field, the list-element with the data-name="abc" should get an different opacity, but it doesnt, you know why?

Comment: There is always a way but as long as I am not sure at all of what you're doing, it's hard to tell. Besides, I stroke out important points for you and offered alternative solutions - apparently those are not good for you?

Comment: Your solutions are not the way i wanna solve it :/ sorry. Take a look at my example: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8468/ , now you see what i wanna do. If the input matches one of the data-name´s, it´s area should get an other opacity/grayscale. but there is no visual effect at the moment. Could you refer directly to this example?

Comment: I have crated a small example for you to strike out, that your code work but the problem is that you're applying it to the wrong tags, which are not meant for the purposes that you want. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mSD72/

Comment: ehm ok, i understand your point, but when i change "#pic" to ".imagefield", there is again no visual effect on the area :/ : http://jsfiddle.net/mSD72/2/ , so which tags do i need to apply to? btw: thx for your help, very kind of you!

Comment: You're welcome! There is no effect, because you can not apply CSS to neither `<map>` nor `<area>` tags but you can do it with JavaScript libraries. Take a look at the source-code of those plugins and see the way they work. Your `.imagefield` refers to `<area>` tag.

Comment: ok thanks, i donwnloaded and put mapper.js on my server, but where can i find "wz_jsgraphics.js" ?? Moreover: i need to implement it in my jquery and not directly in area?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I will not be able to help you on what you're asking, because it's another question, related to `mapper.js`. Please accept my answer in case you feel it was helpful and ask another question. I recommend searching first as most of your questions are already answered! Have a good evening!

Comment: `elternElementDesBildes` - is undefined object? Your js code is incorrect!

Comment: yea, casuze i didnt know exactly what to put there, could you just help with this bit?

Comment: I could, if I had a clear idea of what you're trying to do! We don't know your intentions and as a result we can't offer you an alternative solutions. Apparently you're lost and need to continue learning and trying! There is no other way for none of us!

Comment: changed: http://jsfiddle.net/mSD72/29/ , OK, so: if the input in the input-field matches one of data-name´s of the area-tag´s, this area should get an visual effect. u understand?

Comment: No, I don't understand why you can't accept the fact that you can't style neither `map` nor `area` tags?